# Get String which was added to the url in php

Tags: php, url

I don't know how to google this since I don't know the names of the things I need. I tried some things but didn't get to the point.

Well, I am trying to do something in php where you need to open the webpage with a certain string at the end, which is guiding you to a certain "room".
You get a Code and have to add it to the url ( `localhost` ), like so: `localhost/ABCD` and all I need to do, is reading the `ABCD` and open up `localhost` just like goo.gl is doing it with their shortened URLs.

Right now it's searching for a recource (folder?) in my webspace and can't find it since the `ABCD` is a randomly generated String.

All I could think of right now is creating that folder and place a html file in there that is directly linking back to localhost, but there must be an easier way.

I don't want to use a GET request, because the `?r=ABCD` might be to much for my audience...

Right now it's just a plain textfield, but it could be a bit faster/easier...

Comment: You need to use *htaccess* to achieve this.

Comment: have a look at .htaccess ReWrite Rules! You should find many examples for this!